# Insert checkbox in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, ipywidgets

I want to display a `pandas dataframe` in which at the begining of each row there is a `Checkbox` (`ipywidget`) to know which row the user is selecting.

I have made a frist trial with a `Button` using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from ipywidgets import Button, HBox, VBox,widgets
import ipywidgets
from ipyleaflet import Map

mS2 = Map(center=(40.4, -3.7), zoom=6)

offlineS2 = ['true', 'false']
nameS2 = ['a','b']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': nameS2,'Offile': offlineS2})

# ideally I would need Checkbox not Button
button0 = widgets.Button(description='Click to display')
button1 = widgets.Button()         
button2 = widgets.Button(description='Select')
dfW = ipywidgets.HTML(df.style.set_table_attributes('class="table"').render())

testup = HBox([VBox([button0,button1,button2]),dfW])
display(VBox([testup,mS2]))
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

However, when I change in the code `widgets.Button` by `widgets.Checkbox`, although it is displayed, the distance between the checkbox and the dataframe is too large. Why is this hapenning?

[image]

### EDIT

Using

```
`button1 = widgets.Button(indent=False)`
```

[image]

Comment: Been a while since the last time I used widgets, but I'm pretty sure there's an option to move the checkbox in any direction

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid if you continue to have problems. Otherwise, just remove margin-right with indent. I'll post an example solution.

Answer (score 1):

By default: `indent` is set to True. Change it to `False` and Voilà.

Try this:

```
button0 = widgets.Checkbox(
    description="Click to display", 
    value=True,
    indent=False
)
button1 = widgets.Checkbox(
    description="", 
    value=True,
    indent=False
)
button2 = widgets.Checkbox(
    description="Select", 
    value=True,
    indent=False
)
```

Edit:

Try setting the margin and padding manually for your HBox.

```
verticalItems = VBox([button0,button1,button2], layout=Layout(margin='0 0 0 0', padding='0 0 0 0'))
fullLayout = HBox([verticalItems, dfW], layout=Layout(margin='0 0 0 0', padding='0 0 0 0'))

display(VBox([fullLayout ,mS2]))
```

Comment: I have added a new picture to show the display in this case. It moves the checkbox to the left, but I would like to have it close to the `dataframe`. I was checking this post https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2221 but not sure if it applies @Joel

Comment: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Checkbox

I'm assuming that you only added indent=False on the first one in your latest picture. Also, try `to_html()` instead of `render()`

EDIT: I see your comment now.

Comment: with `to_html` I get `AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_html'`

Comment: see my updated answer and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: getting the same display as in my second picture

Comment: Add indent=False to all checkboxes. The API doesn't provide any other alternative than this for moving your checkboxes. Oherwise, your best bet is to move the entire VBox, or the table.

Comment: changing all the `indent` does not approach the checkbox enough to my `df`. Any idea on how to move the `VBox` or the `table`

Comment: Try setting `widgets.Checkbox(description="Select", layout=Layout(width='30px')), indent=False`. Here's the docs for styling widgets.https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html 
Here's the docs for styling boxes: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#Natural-sizes,-and-arrangements-using-HBox-and-VBox

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up using a `Select` ipywidget to solve my problem as this allows to select an element and retrieve its index.

Comment: No problem! Unfortunate that my answer couldn't help you using checkboxes.

Comment: Actually I think I was having a wrong approach. The idea behind is to let the user select a row. For that, I originally thought about a checkbox to retrive its index. Howver a `Select` widget and its `.index` key makes the job for me. Anyways, thank you :)